# How to open a folder with authentication in c#?

Tags: c#

[image]How to open a folder with authentication in c# ?
I already use LogonUser and it did not work...

```
IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
bool success = LogonUser("username", "domainname", "password",
    2, 0, ref token);
if (success)
{
    using (WindowsImpersonationContext person = new WindowsIdentity(token).Impersonate())
    {
        File.Copy(sourceFileName,destFileName);

        person.Undo();
        CloseHandle(token);
    }
}
```

Succes is true and I receive a number in the token, it enters the if and gives a user error and a password.

> Everything works fine until it reaches the File.Copy part ERROR: I
>   still got this error "Additional information: Logon failure: unknown
>   user name or bad password."

Comment: Q: What is the exact error?  Q: Does it pertain to the source folder, source file, destination folder, user identity, or "something else"?

Comment: Also check the parameters that you are passing to SoddingNetworkAuth, they must be the following items in the following order; User Name, Server Name, Password.

My code take it out of this page
http://webmisterradixlecti.blogspot.com/2012/09/c-accessing-or-copying-files-over.html

Everything works fine until it reaches the File.Copy part

ERROR:
I still got this error "Additional information: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password."

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.* - Point 1 from [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please [edit] your question to move the error from your comment into the question.

Comment: Have you tried the example from msft/docs? It works like a charm:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.impersonate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
**This code works, it is passed the parameters by constructor, but it can be adapted to call it a method**

----------


using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Threading;
    namespace pepe(ejemplo)
    {`enter code here`
        public class NetworkAuthentication
        {

            public string Dom { get; set; }
            public string User { get; set; }
            public string Pwd { get; set; }

            public NetworkAuthentication(string dom, string user, string pwd) {
                this.Dom = dom;
                this.User = user;
                this.Pwd = pwd;
            }

            const int RESOURCETYPE_DISK = 0x00000001;
            const int RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_FILE = 0x00000004;

            const int CONNECT_INTERACTIVE = 0x00000008;
            const int CONNECT_PROMPT = 0x00000010;
            const int CONNECT_UPDATE_PROFILE = 0x00000001;


            #region Constantes recursos - comentados
            /*
            const int RESOURCE_CONNECTED = 0x00000001;
            const int RESOURCE_GLOBALNET = 0x00000002;
            const int RESOURCE_REMEMBERED = 0x00000003;
            const int RESOURCETYPE_ANY = 0x00000000;
            const int RESOURCETYPE_PRINT = 0x00000002;
            const int RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_GENERIC = 0x00000000;
            const int RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_DOMAIN = 0x00000001;
            const int RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_SERVER = 0x00000002;
            const int RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_SHARE = 0x00000003;
            const int RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_GROUP = 0x00000005;
            const int RESOURCEUSAGE_CONNECTABLE = 0x00000001;
            const int RESOURCEUSAGE_CONTAINER = 0x00000002;
            const int CONNECT_REDIRECT = 0x00000080;
            const int CONNECT_COMMANDLINE = 0x00000800;
            const int CONNECT_CMD_SAVECRED = 0x00001000;
            const int CONNECT_LOCALDRIVE = 0x00000100;
             */
            #endregion

            #region Errors - Comentada

            /*
            const int NO_ERROR = 0;
            const int ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED = 5;
            const int ERROR_ALREADY_ASSIGNED = 85;
            const int ERROR_BAD_DEVICE = 1200;
            const int ERROR_BAD_NET_NAME = 67;
            const int ERROR_BAD_PROVIDER = 1204;
            const int ERROR_CANCELLED = 1223;
            const int ERROR_EXTENDED_ERROR = 1208;
            const int ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS = 487;
            const int ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER = 87;
            const int ERROR_INVALID_PASSWORD = 1216;
            const int ERROR_MORE_DATA = 234;
            const int ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS = 259;
            const int ERROR_NO_NET_OR_BAD_PATH = 1203;
            const int ERROR_NO_NETWORK = 1222;
            const int ERROR_BAD_PROFILE = 1206;
            const int ERROR_CANNOT_OPEN_PROFILE = 1205;
            const int ERROR_DEVICE_IN_USE = 2404;
            const int ERROR_NOT_CONNECTED = 2250;
            const int ERROR_OPEN_FILES = 2401;
            private struct ErrorClass
            {
                public int num;
                public string message;
                public ErrorClass(int num, string message)
                {
                    this.num = num;
                    this.message = message;
                }
            }

            // Created with excel formula:
  // ="new ErrorClass("&A1&", """&PROPER(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,7,LEN(A1)-6), _","))&"""), "
            private static ErrorClass[] ERROR_LIST = new ErrorClass[] {
                new ErrorClass(ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED, "Error: Access Denied"), 
                new ErrorClass(ERROR_ALREADY_ASSIGNED, "Error: Already Assigned"), 
                new ErrorClass(ERROR_BAD_DEVICE, "Error: Bad Device"), 
                new ErrorClass(ERROR_BAD_NET_NAME, "Error: Bad Net Name"), 
                new ErrorClass(ERROR_BAD_PROVIDER, "Error: Bad Provider"), 
                new ErrorClass(ERROR_CANCELLED, "Error: Cancelled"), 
                new ErrorClass(ERROR_EXTENDED_ERROR, "Error: Extended Error"), 
                new ErrorClass(ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS, "Error: Invalid Address"), 
                new ErrorClass(ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER, "Error: Invalid Parameter"), 
                new ErrorClass(ERROR_INVALID_PASSWORD, "Error: Invalid Password"), 
                new ErrorClass(ERROR_MORE_DATA, "Error: More Data"), 
                new ErrorClass(ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS, "Error: No More Items"), 
                new ErrorClass(ERROR_NO_NET_OR_BAD_PATH, "Error: No Net Or Bad Path"), 
                new ErrorClass(ERROR_NO_NETWORK, "Error: No Network"), 
                new ErrorClass(ERROR_BAD_PROFILE, "Error: Bad Profile"), 
                new ErrorClass(ERROR_CANNOT_OPEN_PROFILE, "Error: Cannot Open Profile"), 
                new ErrorClass(ERROR_DEVICE_IN_USE, "Error: Device In Use"), 
                new ErrorClass(ERROR_EXTENDED_ERROR, "Error: Extended Error"), 
                new ErrorClass(ERROR_NOT_CONNECTED, "Error: Not Connected"), 
                new ErrorClass(ERROR_OPEN_FILES, "Error: Open Files"), 
            };
            private static string getErrorForNumber(int errNum)
            {
                foreach (ErrorClass er in ERROR_LIST)
                {
                    if (er.num == errNum) return er.message;
                }
                return "Error: Unknown, " + errNum;
            }
             */
            #endregion



            [DllImport("Mpr.dll")]
            private static extern int WNetUseConnection(
                IntPtr hwndOwner,
                NETRESOURCE lpNetResource,
                string lpPassword,
                string lpUserID,
                int dwFlags,
                string lpAccessName,
                string lpBufferSize,
                string lpResult
                );
            [DllImport("Mpr.dll")]
            private static extern int WNetCancelConnection2(
                string lpName,
                int dwFlags,
                bool fForce
                );
            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            private class NETRESOURCE
            {
                public int dwScope = 0;
                public int dwType = 0;
                public int dwDisplayType = 0;
                public int dwUsage = 0;
                public string lpLocalName = "";
                public string lpRemoteName = "";
                public string lpComment = "";
                public string lpProvider = "";
            }

            public string connectToRemote()
            {
                NETRESOURCE nr = new NETRESOURCE();
                nr.dwType = RESOURCETYPE_DISK;
                nr.lpRemoteName = this.Dom;
                //          nr.lpLocalName = "F:";
                int ret = WNetUseConnection(IntPtr.Zero, nr, this.Pwd, this.User, 0, null, null, null);           
                //Chequear en la region de errores si el retorno es distinto de cero a que corresponde
                if (ret == 0) return null;
                return "Error";
            }
            public string disconnectRemote()
            {
                int ret = WNetCancelConnection2(this.Dom, CONNECT_UPDATE_PROFILE, false);
                //Chequear en la region de errores si el retorno es distinto de cero a que corresponde
                if (ret == 0) return null;
                return "Error";

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**I changed the code and it worked for me correctly, I leave it here in case someone needs it.**

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace BBVA.Canales.Front.Net.UI.WebApp.Servicios.ViewModels
{
    public class NetworkShare
    {
        [DllImport("Mpr.dll")]
        private static extern int WNetUseConnection(
            IntPtr hwndOwner,
            NETRESOURCE lpNetResource,
            string lpPassword,
            string lpUserID,
            int dwFlags,
            string lpAccessName,
            string lpBufferSize,
            string lpResult
            );

        [DllImport("Mpr.dll")]
        private static extern int WNetCancelConnection(
            string lpName,
            bool fForce
            );

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private class NETRESOURCE
        {
            public int dwScope = 0;
            public int dwType = 0;
            public int dwDisplayType = 0;
            public int dwUsage = 0;
            public string lpLocalName = "";
            public string lpRemoteName = "";
            public string lpComment = "";
            public string lpProvider = "";
        }

        const int RESOURCETYPE_DISK = 0x00000001;
        const int CONNECT_UPDATE_PROFILE = 0x00000001;


        public static void ConnectToShare(string uri, string username, string password, string idFile, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            //Create netresource and point it at the share
            NETRESOURCE nr = new NETRESOURCE();
            nr.dwType = RESOURCETYPE_DISK;
            nr.lpRemoteName = uri;

            //Create the share
            int ret = WNetUseConnection(IntPtr.Zero, nr, password, username, 0, null, null, null);

            file.SaveAs(@"\\c:\Desktop\FolderName\" + idFile);

        }

        public static void DisconnectFromShare(string uri, bool force)
        {
            //remove the share
            int ret = WNetCancelConnection(uri, force);

        }



    }
}
```

---

Then from your code you call it with:

```
 ConnectToShare("dom", @"user", @"psw", file);
  DisconnectFromShare("dom", false);
```